# is submitting a form with >100 fields slower than a smaller form

Tags: performance, forms, submit, slowdown

We have a form which has ca 100 fields. There is no javascript involved in submitting it, just a timer that is stopped with

```
<button type="submit" id="apply-button" name="form[submit]" onclick="window.clearInterval(timer);"><span>Apply</span></button>
```

Some users report the form to "stall", ie. it takes up to 1 minute before the form is submitted and the result page shown.

Is submitting a form with a large number of fields a known problem in any browser? If yes, are there tools to measure the time it takes?

Comment: To answer your second question, Google Chrome has tools for that in the Dev Tools (Ctrl+Shift+I)

Answer (score 1):

Every field that gets submitted must be sent to the server through the user's connection.

If the user has a slow upstream connection, larger forms will take longer.

Comment: I agree. Can't see any browser choking on 100 fields but if they have a slow upstream connection it could be an issue.

Comment: But I don't doubt there is a linear correlation between the number of fields and form submission.

Comment: @parapurarajkumar: I haven't measured, but I would assume that the overhead for each field is miniscule.